# Excel spreadsheet Formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to insert the word "Due" if the date in `M5` is greater or equal to the `N5` date and also check if the date in `N5` is greater or equal to today’s date. 
I need this formula to check if `N5` is greater or less than today’s date as well? How can this be done?

```
=IF(M5>=N5,"Due","OK")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `OR()` function:

```
=IF(OR(M5>=N5,N5>=TODAY()), "Due", "OK")
```

Comment: 'today()' updates whenever cells are updated. It is possible that you could be viewing the spreadsheet, and the cell values are showing results using an old value for 'today()'. It could be worth adding a button attached to VB code that refreshes formulae to help the user be certain that today is using the correct data.

Comment: Or just press F9?

Comment: Thanks mate you nailed it, I was unsure where to place the OR.

Comment: sure, but there are a lot of admin people in my business who can't press keys on the keyboard and big colourful 'refresh' buttons seem to work

Comment: And do they leave Excel open overnight (or work through the night)? Because I think that would be the only case in which this would be an issue; Excel re-evaluates volatile functions when you open a spreadsheet, right?